# Issues running ganache-cli command options

Tags: ganache

So I open ganache-cli on one window.
And from ganache-cli github repo I can see all those command options, but don't understand where to run them..

Answer (score 0):

On the terminal (cmd in windows) from command line you can type the commands you need

```
$ ganache-cli [options]
```

p.s. if you opened the GUI you have to close it to avoid conflicts since they might use the same port (unless you change it)

Comment: You mean new another terminal, or the same one you started ganache-cli with?

Comment: if you want to run ganache-cli with options just provide it in the command line, if not run it without options and it will use the default values. If you're already able to run ganache-cli I'm missing the question then. Whats the issue?

Comment: Ahhh, sorry for explanation. I want to be able to check for example, balances of dummy accounts before and after deploying contracts. Or do I just have to do this on remix..?

Comment: that's different then. You can use web3 for that after opening ganache-cli. Don't know if ganache-cli accepts commands in the console, geth does.

Comment: I'm confused, ganache-cli in my project directory to open testrpc. Then other terminal geth attach?

Comment: yes, unless you use web3 via your app